# MVVMCross Binding decimal to UITextField removes decimal point

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Binding a decimal to a UITextField does not let you put a "." in, as you type "1.", the push to source strips it out. I get why it happens, MakeSafeValue converts it to a decimal, which gets read back out without the ".", overwriting the Text entered. This seems like a keyup vs onblur issue, which a lot of binding frameworks let you override.

I know I could bind a string on the view model instead, but handling the EditingDidEnd instead of EditingChanged seems better. That way I could intercept ShouldEndEditing to check validity.

Where would I register my binding to override the MvvmCross implementation? I tried adding in my Setup.FillTargetFactories, but it is called before MVXTouchBindingBuilder.FillTargetFactories where the MvvmCross one is.

I tried a different property name, in FillTargetFactories I have:

```
registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(typeof (UITextFieldTextDidEndTargetBinding), typeof (UITextField), "DidEndText");
```

but it does not work when I bind.

```
set.Bind(textField).For("DidEndText").To(vm => vm.GMoney);
```

looks like MvxPropertyInfoTargetBindingFactory.CreateBinding does not work if the target does not have that property = makes sense. Does this leave me with starting at MvxTargetBinding and creating a custom binding? I hate to recreate most of the code in MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.

So, I guess the question(s) are...

- what is the syntax/location to override the default UITextField binding with mine?
- how can I specify a different binding for Text with the Bind Syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the syntax/location to override the default UITextField binding with mine?

If you want to simply replace the existing binding, then you can do this via the `RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory` extension method.

MvvmCross operates a simple 'last registered wins' system.

The easiest place your registration in order that happens last is to place it at the end of `InitializeLastChance` in your `Setup`:

```
 protected override void InitializeLastChance()
 {
     base.InitializeLastChance();

     var factory = base.Resolve<IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry>();
     factory.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(
                     typeof(MyBindingType),
                     typeof(UITextField),
                     "Text");
 }
```

There's some more info on order of initialization/setup in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup (work in progress).

> how can I specify a different binding for Text with the Bind Syntax?

The line:

```
     registry.RegisterPropertyInfoBindingFactory(
            typeof (UITextFieldTextDidEndTargetBinding), 
            typeof (UITextField), 
            "DidEndText");
```

doesn't work because it tries to use a property called `DidEndText` - which doesn't exist.

Two possible ways around this are:

**1 Subclass `UITextField` to provide a real property**

```
   public class MyTextField : UITextField
   {
        // ctors

        public string MySpecialText
        {
            get { return base.Text; }
            set { base.Text = value; }
        }
   }
```

An example of `UITextField` subclassing is shown in [the N=33 video](https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-33-AnimateTextChanges/TextChange.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs)

**2 Or use a non-propertyInfo-based binding**

For known properties and event pairs this is pretty simple to do:

```
public class MySpecialBinding : MvxTargetBinding
{
    public MySpecialBinding (UIEditField edit)
        : base(edit)
    {
        edit.SpecialEvent += Handler;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            var text = (UITextField)Target;
            if (text != null)
            {
                text.SpecialEvent -= Handler;
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }

    protected override void Handler(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = (UITextField)target;
        if (text == null)
            return;
        FireValueChanged(text.Text);
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.TwoWay; }
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(string); }
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        var text = (UITextField)target;
        if (text == null)
            return;
        text.Text = value;
    }
}
```

This *special* binding can be registered using `RegisterCustomBindingFactory`

```
registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<UITextField>(
        "FooFlipper", 
        textField => new MySpecialBinding(textField));
```

After which bindings like:

```
set.Bind(textField).For("FooFlipper").To(vm => vm.GMoney);
```

will work.

---

As well as your 'use a string in the ViewModel' suggestion, another possible workaround for this double-text conversion, might be to use a two-way value converter. If your UI is handling money, this could insist on displaying decimal places for all values.

Comment: One final thing - For your particular problem/challenge, I think MvvmCross would be interested in fixes/suggestions if you can think of any... (although first I'll also put some time aside to setup a test harness for this - not something I've seen before in e.g. tipcalc)

Comment: I created a repository to show some ways to handle the issue: https://github.com/brianchance/MonoTouchMVVMCrossValidationTester, let me know if it is not clear. Learned a lot about MVVMCross during this exercise.

Comment: Some suggestions I can think of would be to allow passing options to the binder from the bind syntax (like Changing vs EndEdit) so they can be more flexible. Something like set.Bind(field).Options(new {EndEdit = true}).To(vm => vm.SomeField);, Another suggestion would be to publish conversion errors using the messenger or hooking an event so feedback could be given.