# Mvvmcross bind to Visibility with autolayout and fully hide view

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Currently binding to "Visibility" sets Hidden=true. How would you create a generic Visibility binding which also changes a constraint: sets the view height to 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

For a tutorial on creating bindings, see the N=28 video on http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com/

To replace the existing visibility binding, simply create your own class based on https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Target/MvxUIViewVisibleTargetBinding.cs

```
public class MyUIViewVisibleTargetBinding : MvxBaseUIViewVisibleTargetBinding
{
    public MyUIViewVisibleTargetBinding(UIView target)
        : base(target)
    {
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var view = View;
        if (view == null)
            return;

        var visible = value.ConvertToBoolean();
        // your code here
        // - in place of or in addition to:
        // view.Hidden = !visible;
    }
}
```

And register this as the last step in `Setup` using:

```
protected override void InitializeLastChance()
{
     base.InitializeLastChance();

     var registry = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry>();
     registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<UIView>("Visible",
                                                    view =>
                                                    new MyUIViewVisibleTargetBinding(view));
```

}

For more on replacing existing bindings, see [MVVMCross Binding decimal to UITextField removes decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603755/mvvmcross-binding-decimal-to-uitextfield-removes-decimal-point)

---

Note that if you want to replace all `Visible` bindings, then you might want to replace all of `Visible`, `Visibility` and `Hidden` - see registrations in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/MvxTouchBindingBuilder.cs#L42

Comment: well i know how to create bindings, just would like to find a generic way of enabling/disabling some constraints : the ones which sets the view height. A generic way. Maybe by enumerating all constraints from subviews which link to the container view + any height constraints on the container view itself, disabling them, and setting a new one which forces a 0 height. But reenabling constraints would need to know which one were disabled.

Comment: I think a longer question might - it might help answerers to work out what you are asking. Maybe try editing your question to give a full description - preferably with code - of what you have setup and what you want the binding to change. For further inspiration, JS has some good advice on asking questions on https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Well sorry if we didn't understand each other Stuart. You don't need to tackle me. I should not have put mvvmcross in this question.